# Trying to complete the DJANGO intro tutorial as seen on the w3schools website - https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_intro.php

Tags: django, django-views

Following along the tutorial as seen on https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_intro.php

Basically I have:

1. Created virtual environment
2. Started Django project - myworld
3. Created a members app and edited the views exactly as mentioned
4. Added to urls.py in the project and members directory

Still get this error that empty path didn't match any of these

[A screenshot of the error message I am seeing instead of Hello world! and welcome to Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l6DJ.png)

[A screenshot of my urls.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8gUr.png)

Is this an issue with me being in a wrong path, or do I need to specify more in path('blog', ) section?

Comment: Please can you share code within the question instead of linking to images, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/members` URL as you can see in your urls.py you have specified paths as `path('members/', include('members.urls'))`.